# How to retrieve the key value from configuration file using java

Tags: java

I tried to read webconfig file in java.Im getting the below error.

```
java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:80)
    at java.util.Properties$XmlSupport.load(Properties.java:1201)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:881)
    at Extensions.Utilities.ReadValueFromXmlPropertyFile(Utilities.java:46)
    at Extensions.Utilities.main(Utilities.java:30)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.getLoadingDoc(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:106)
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.java:78)
    ... 4 more
```

This is my code:

```
 public static String ReadValueFromXmlPropertyFile(String Key,
                    String Filename) {
                String KeyValue = null;
                try {
                //  File file = new File(userDir+"/"+ Filename);
                    File file = new File(Filename);
                    FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);

                    Properties prop = new Properties();
                    prop.loadFromXML(fileInput);

                    KeyValue = prop.getProperty(Key);

                    System.out.println(Key+"-->"+KeyValue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return KeyValue;
            }
```

### and This is web config file contents:

```
<add key="DateOfBirthPopUp" value="False"/>
<add key="DOBMaxAge" value="19"/>
<add key="DOBMinAge" value="12"/>
```

and web config file does'nt have

`<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Change the webconfig.xml to below and try,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Here are some favorites</comment>
<entry key="DateOfBirthPopUp">False</entry>
<entry key="DOBMaxAge">19</entry>
<entry key="DOBMinAge">12</entry>
</properties>
```

May be you want to read [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-properties-from-an-xml-file.html).

Comment: but in our application we are not using this statement in any configuration file...i wan tto know why this statement is needed in xml file and why the loadxml() method is searching whether "<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">" is present or not...